# Opencart showing some links as https without ssl enabled

Tags: php, opencart, e-commerce

I have installed the latest version (3.0.2.0) of Opencart. It is showing some links as https even when there is no SSL certificate installed and ssl url are disabled from admin dashboard.

When I looked in "C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\catalog\controller\common\footer.php" I found that some urls have ssl enabled like below

```
    $data['voucher'] = $this->url->link('account/voucher', '', true);
    $data['affiliate'] = $this->url->link('affiliate/login', '', true);
    $data['special'] = $this->url->link('product/special');
    $data['account'] = $this->url->link('account/account', '', true);
    $data['order'] = $this->url->link('account/order', '', true);
    $data['wishlist'] = $this->url->link('account/wishlist', '', true);
    $data['newsletter'] = $this->url->link('account/newsletter', '', true);
```

What to do to run these url's without editing the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change HTTPS_SERVER in your config.php and admin/config.php file. (change `https://` to `http://`)